# Logical mistake in adding only a 10-digit number to the database in Android

Tags: android, logic

What i want is the number which is stored inside edittext variable 'num' should only be inserted into the table  myNumber only when exactly 10 numbers are inserted. Else it should show the message

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

which I have given inside the code

```
pc = passcode.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("CHECK","PASSCODE"+pc.trim().length());
                     lc = lockcode.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("CHECK","LOCKCODE"+lc.trim().length());
                    num=number.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("CHECK","NUMBER"+num.trim().length());
                    if (pc.trim().length() > 0 && lc.trim().length() > 0 && num.trim().length()>0) {
                        if (lc.length() < 4 || lc.length() > 9 && num.length()!=10) {
                            if(num.length()!=10)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password must be metween 4-9 characters long", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myNumber VALUES('" + num + "')");
                            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES('" + pc + "')");
                            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO myPhone VALUES('" + lc + "')");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent dialogboxintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FAQ.class);
                            startActivity(dialogboxintent);
                            /*passcode.setText(" ");
                            lockcode.setText(" ");*/
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter something valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

All 3 variables num,pc and lc are inserted into the database at the same time.Everything works just fine here except the fact that the variable num will insert anything into the database that is not null. The other conditions work just like I want to. Can anyone fill me with logic here?

Answer (score 0):

Try This to validate.

```
String valid = validatePhoneNumber("7744552211");
if(valid.equals("valid"){
  //Insert into database
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


 public static String validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNo) {
    String isValid = "inValid";
    if(phoneNo.equals("")){
        isValid = "empty";
    }else{
        String expression = "^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$";  
        CharSequence inputStr = phoneNo;  
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);  
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  
        if(matcher.matches()){  
        isValid = "valid";  
        }
    }
    return isValid;  
    }
```